# Conditional filter in RxJava2

Tags: java, reactivex

I have a method with a signature

```
void supplyData(String query, Integer skip, Integer count)
```

Typically I would model the method body like this:

```
MyProvider.observable(query)
 .skip(skip)
  .take(count)
  .subscribe();
```

Now the two Integers could be null, so I don’t need to skip and take all. How can I make these two steps optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` check should work here,

```
MyProvider.observable(query)
 .skip(skip == null? 0: skip)
 .take(count == null? Integer.MAX_VALUE: count)
 .subscribe();
```